# Symfony - Applications run without Apache server

Tags: php, apache, symfony, internal-server-error

I used to think that the internal web server which SYMFONY uses is part of APACHE server, which runs with the following command:

```
$ php bin/console server:start
```

But as I turn off the Apache server on my PC (windows 10) the internal web server still producing without any problems, so is it that the internal web server has nothing to do with the Apache server or it's something unusual?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP provides a standalone [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.webserver.php).

You can try it by running `php -S localhost:3000 -t web` at the root directory of your project then browsing `http://localhost:3000/app_dev.php`.

All commands that are part of the `server:*` namespace are related to the [PHP built-in server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html).

For more informations, look at [the command](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Command/ServerStartCommand.php) directly.

Answer (score 0):

it is using PHP build in server

Comment: Take the time to write clean answers give more benefits on the long term.